# Use bpy update View Node from compositor nodes before saving

Tags: python, compositing-nodes

I want to save edits from the compositor using the viewer node to make edits to an image without re-rendering, however, it appears that because the nodes are also set up in python, this code does not calculate the nodes before saving. What am I missing?

```
import bpy
import os
viewer_image = bpy.data.images['Viewer Node']
download_folder = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Downloads')
output_path = os.path.join(download_folder, "viewer_output.png")
viewer_image.filepath = output_path
viewer_image.file_format = 'PNG'

saved_shadow = viewer_image.save()
```

[image]